# How To use load listener in Extjs4

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am learning how to utilize the load event ..how do i go about
catching the loading of data.. I just n4ed  a sample example.. to understand how it works and how data is manipulated inside the callback function

Thanks

```
store.addListener("load", dataLoadCallback);


function dataLoadCallBack((store, records, success))


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
store.on('load',/*event*/,dataLoadcallback /*function called*/, this/*scope called*/) 

function dataLoadBackCalled(store, records){ //dont stress about success just yet.
  store.each(function(record)){
      console.log(record.get('id');
  }
}
```

Heres a nice post on how to do listeners: http://mitchellsimoens.com/2011/12/ext-js-4/ext-define-and-listeners-as-a-property-bad/